# Sending a GA4 Event's float parameter as a STRING

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I'm trying to send user's client ID (which usually is 20 digits separated with a `.`)  to GA4  through GTM's GA4 Event's `User Properties`.

The problem is that Client ID parameter is interpreted as a float number when it reaches GA4 (`1.5437e+09`) and it rounds it up, or drops last few numbers.

Adding a letter to a parameter, something like "`S_{{client_id}}`" does help, but I'm looking for a cleaner solution.

Using JS to convert client ID specifically to string, with `.toString()` method, also does not work, making GA4 still interpret it as a float number.

So my question is, **how to set a parameter's type on GTM to be sent specifically as a STRING, even if it's a float number?**

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, that's currently not possible. Google is trying to be (too) smart and automatically casts numeric values into a number type.

A similar solution to yours, but maybe a little bit less intrusive, is to append a `.` to the end of your value thereby forcing Google to parse the value as a string. (`{{client_id}}.`)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this! In my case, I was sending UPC or EAN codes to GA4, which are NOT numbers, they are codes. A UPC can have leading zeros (e.g. 0732064976655). GA4 was converting my codes into integers which would remove the leading zeros, thereby corrupting my data. I was able to solve this issue by wrapping my UPC codes using "zero width space" characters before putting it into the JSON I send in my web service call to GA4.

What is a "zero width space" character? It is described on this page:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space

Since the stackoverflow page is HTML, I can't type in the character code because it won't display it. So, I will type it here with spaces in between the various characters: '& # 8 2 0 3 ;' Remove the spaces and that is the character code.

All I did was concat('& # 8 2 0 3 ;','0732064976655','& # 8 2 0 3 ;') and added it to my JSON value in my web service call to GA4.

I checked BigQuery and it saved my UPC or EAN code as a string!

Comment: There is one downside to this solution, I discovered that I have to use a LIKE and wild cards in my query to retrieve the data. For example:
SELECT * 
FROM `MY_TABLE_NAME` 
WHERE (SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'upc') LIKE '%8809934297676%'
Order by event_date DESC LIMIT 1000


However, if I export the data in CSV or JSON, the zero width space characters don't appear to be in the output.

It is not a perfect solution but it is better than having my UPC code data corrupted.

Comment: Upon further reflection, this solution is no better than wrapping your data in single quotes, except these zero width space characters are invisible, which might create some hard to find bugs in your queries.